# Assigning value to ng-value or ng-init from Ajax Success Block

Tags: ajax, angularjs

Could not find any examples/Code Samples on the web.Just setting the value attributes doesn't work with angular so wanted to know if there is any other way of setting the value for the input box.

```
<input id="company_name" ng-model="company.name" type="text">
```

Wanted to set the value to the AJAX response received.

Comment: and what is stopping you to update the company name after ajax? can you show how you are setting the value after ajax?

Comment: The examples given on the web $scope.company.name = data.name <- received from ajax and then $scope.apply() doesn't work. Is there something wrong

Comment: can you add a fiddle with your example?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e7fdqr6p/1/ Here is a part of the code > .The script is triggered correctly by an onclick event. Ajax is working correctly. I tried printing the Ajax response and it is working  correctly as well. Just missing the assignment to the form input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bind the input to a property in the controller, call a function in ng-click and set the property value:

```
    function myCtrl(DataService){
      var vm= this;
      vm.getData = function(){
      DataService.getData().then(function(res){
        vm.company = res;
      });
    }

<input id="company_name" ng-model="company.name" type="text" >
<button ng-click="ctrl.getData()">Get Data</button>
```

Comment: I am not assigning the values during initialization. Will the function be triggered for the ng-value?

Comment: call the function in ng-click

Comment: Is there no direct way like normal JS to directly assign the result to the input box? Like  `$('#company_region').val(data.country);` Just find the the id or ng-model and set its ng-value?